# Why's it all being displayed as Big Number if I am using ethers.utils.parseEther? Is this normally how it displays in console?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, ethers.js, hardhat

In my hardhat test file I am converting ERC20 tokens transactions/balances with ethers.utils.parseEther like...

```
const ONE_ETHER = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
```

So if everything is being converted why is showing in my console **BigNumber** for all the values? Is this normally how it would display or am I not converting correctly. Here is screenshot...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for the values to be displayed as a **BigNumber** in the console, even after converting them with **ethers.utils.parseEther**.

[**BigNumber**](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber) is a data type used by the [Ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/) library to represent large numbers with high precision, which is necessary when dealing with cryptocurrency transactions and balances. When you convert a number using **ethers.utils.parseEther**, it returns a **BigNumber** object representing the same value.

Logging this **BigNumber** object to the console will display it as a **BigNumber** rather than a regular number. This is because **BigNumber** objects have properties and methods that differ from regular JavaScript numbers.

If you need to perform any mathematical operations with the converted value, you can use the [**BigNumber** methods](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--methods) provided by the ethers.js library. For example, you can add two converted values together like this:

```js
const balance1 = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.5");
const balance2 = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.5");
const totalBalance = balance1.add(balance2);
console.log(totalBalance.toString());
```

Chaining the **toString()** method to a **bigNumber** will output the total balance as a string, which you can then display or use in your code as needed.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

parseEther converts a string to BigNumber. You can use formatEther to format BigNubmers to strings.